In nodejs (sequelize), Add new key or column in MySql via migration
In nodejs (sequelize) ,Add new key or column in MySql via migration but it is not defined in the model so how it update automatically in the model
I have make new migration on adding new column and the column is added successfully and it shows in the db also. But while doing any operation like adding then it is not adding in that particular column because that particular column is not in the modal.
so while migrating automatically modal should be updated. currenty i have to put manually that key in the modal
